# Basis and dimension of the null space and range

Tags: linear-algebra

The linear map $T : \Bbb R^{n\times n}\to \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is defined by the formula

$$T(A) = \frac12(A+A^T)\;.$$

- How do I find a basis of the null space of $T$ and determine its dimension? and
- How do I find a basis of the range of $T$ and determine its dimension?

Comment: Can you think of any elements of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that are in the null space? Once you see what it means to be in the nullspace, the problem becomes simpler. For the other part, the trick is, similarly, to figure out: what interesting property do all elements of the range have?

Comment: If $0 = T(A) = \frac{1}{2} (A + A^T)$, what can you say about $A$ and $A^T$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: By definition $A$ is in the null space of $T$ if and only if $T(A)$ is the zero matrix, $\Bbb O$; for which $A\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is it true that

$$\frac12(A+A^T)=\Bbb O\;?$$

Once you’ve answered that, it shouldn’t be too hard to find a basis and hence the dimension.

For the range, notice that $A+A^T$ always has a certain special property, and it’s not hard to show that every $n\times n$ real matrix with that property is of the form $A+A^T$; what is that property? Once you’ve identified it, it shouldn’t be hard to identify the range of $T$.